# Node.js App is not recognizing src file path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am currently trying to build a simple quiz app, in this situation I am attempting to src a JS file in an html template. For some reason everytime I run my node app the html file is unable to reference the file, even though the path is correct. I have tried moving the file and have done many different file paths.[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9iw5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiobA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJhfR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mccS.png)

As noted above I tried moving the file to different folders, into the root folder and have tried naming different paths. This app is using express and mongodb to note. The JS is known to work since I embedded it into the html to check it works.

**Index.js file:**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const hbs = require("hbs"); //for hbs files
const collection = require("./mongodb");

const tempelatePath = path.join(__dirname, "./templates");

app.use(express.json()); //To get hbs files
app.set("view engine", "hbs"); //Our view engine will be hbs
app.set("views", tempelatePath); //For the looks
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })); //to get the code to run
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // Serve static files

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("login");
  });
  
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
  res.render("signup");
});

app.get("/quiz", (req, res) => {
  res.render("quiz");
});

app.get("/quizTwo", (req, res) => {
res.render("quizTwo");
});

app.get("/quizThree", (req, res) => {
  res.render("quizThree");
  });
  



app.post("/signup", async (req, res) => {
  const data = {
    name: req.body.name,
    password: req.body.password,
  };

  try {
    await collection.create(data);
    res.render("home");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error inserting data");
  }
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const check = await collection.findOne({ name: req.body.name }); //checking if user exists

    if (check.password === req.body.password) {
      res.render("home");
    } else {
      res.send("Password is incorrect");
    }
  } catch {
    res.send("No Account found");
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Connection made");
});
```

**MongoDb file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const connectionOptions = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ChooseAdventure", connectionOptions) //Setting up Mongo connection

const db = mongoose.connection

db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Error connecting to MongoDB:"))
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB!")
})

const LogInSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
})

const collection = mongoose.model("CollectionOne", LogInSchema)

module.exports = collection
```

**quiz.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Haunted Adventure Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="quiz-container">
      <!-- Quiz questions and choices will be inserted here -->
    </div>
    <button onclick="displayQuiz()">Start Quiz</button>

    <script src="../quiz.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What directory is quick.js in?

Comment: They are in the src folder.

Comment: What's the full URL of the HTML page?

Comment: If you have a js file that is being served by an express app, you need to move that JS file to a directory that the html file has access too.

Comment: https://github.com/OsmanElias/ChooseYourOwnAdventure

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information you provided in the comments of your question, you currently have **quiz.js** in your **src** directory, which cannot serve static content to your frontend. You must serve the JS file from a static directory.

Furthermore, you have this line of code in your example code above -

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // Serve static files
```

This line of code is telling us that you intend on serving static files from the public directory. Based on that line of code, you should move **quiz.jz** to the **public** directory.

At that point, you should be able to include quiz.js like this -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Haunted Adventure Quiz</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="quiz-container">
      <!-- Quiz questions and choices will be inserted here -->
    </div>
    <button onclick="displayQuiz()">Start Quiz</button>

    <script src="quiz.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**Summarizing based on comments conversation -**

Step 1, move **public** to **src** directory, so it is sitting directly next to **templates** directory.

Step 2, change your import to look like this, `<script src="quiz.js"></script>`

Comment: It still is not working even after moving the file to the public folder and changing the directory to /public/quiz.js

Comment: https://github.com/OsmanElias/ChooseYourOwnAdventure here is the github if needed to see all the files.

Comment: Your public directory should be inside the src directory.

Comment: Imagine that your app is going to live on a server (cause it is). Everything can't be accessible from the internet. You designate which files will be served when someone request to the server. In your case, your template files, and the files you put in public. Now to make that work, you need to move public into the src directory. I can see you have other files in there too so you are probably dealing with other issues like this when you try to use those files too.

Comment: Moved it into src and used the /public/quiz.js to reference it, but I am still getting the error : Cannot GET /public/quiz.js

Comment: Can you use any of the files in public?

Comment: Wait, how are you starting this application? Are you using npm? I don't see a start script in your package.json.

Comment: No I tried using login.css which is in the public folder but no luck

Comment: Are you double-clicking the html file to run your app? Or running a script to start the app?

Comment: I am just running "node src/index.js" through my terminal, then connecting to localhost to see the results.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Remove public from the path after moving the directory to src.

Comment: Will the path look like this now then "/src/quiz.js" ?

Comment: Check my edits at the bottom of my answer above. Also, to test this you can add something like body {background-color: coral; } to your CSS file in public and see if you can see the color change when you run the app. Small steps are easier to test.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Might I ask why I had to move public in src?

Comment: You need to read about express and file structures in the express app. Please accept answer if it solved your problem!